# Validate that Name field contains text only

Tags: javascript, html

I want that Name field should contain text only.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        Name <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do so using either HTML or Javascript.

Comment: a simple search on Google would suffice ..

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex in your Javascript: `/^[a-z]+$/i`

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yg7mu/4/)

Javascript:

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener("click", checkInput, false);

function checkInput(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pattern = /^[a-z]+$/i;
    alert(pattern.test(document.getElementById('text').value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether there's "anything left" after removing alpha characters.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return checkform();">
  Name<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function checkform(){
  var fname=document.getElementById('fname').value;
  if (fname.replace(/\w/g,'')!=''||fname==''){
    alert('invalid firstname!');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    var allowedChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var n=form1.fname.value;
    for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++){
        if(allowedChars.indexOf(n.charAt(i))==-1){
            return false; // contains other char
        }
    }
    return true; //valid name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions like

```
 var  match_text = /[a-zA-Z]/;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `var regx = /^[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z ]+$/;`

```
 function validate_form();
 {  

    var regx = /^[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z ]+$/;

    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    if(fname=="")
    {
      alert("Name is Blank");
      return false;
    }
    else if(!regx.test(fname))
    {
        alert("name must contains character only");
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern checking of the textbox must be done with Javascript or Jquery like in other answers **BUT** if you want to use HTML5, you can directly write :

```
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" />
```

*(See 'pattern' attribute in HTML5 if you're interested).*

Comment: (note: not supported by older browsers, namely IE)

Comment: Yeah earlier versions of IE and Safari are not supported but I assumed them to be Old enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function to validate input field containing only text--

```
   function validate()
    {
     str = document.form1.fname.value;
     var patt = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]*$");
     var res = patt.test(str);
     if(!res)
     {
      alert("do not match!");
      return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `new RegExp` instead of the regex literal  `/.../`?

Comment: When using regex literals ,you need to escape the backslashes from string. That is my reason to use RegExp object.Otherwise any of two can be used to check for regular expression.